# Excel Formula - get the date of a maximal value within a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a rather big (long) table and need to do something quite simple but I'm currently with a sort of blackout...

Imagine that you have:

```
Date 1    Value 1    Date 2    Value 2    Date 3    Value 3    Date of MAX
...       ...        ...       ...        ...       ...        ????
```

I want to deploy in `????` a formula that will result in the date at which the maximal value (between Value 1...3) was registered. For instance:

```
Date 1    Value 1    Date 2    Value 2    Date 3    Value 3    Date of MAX
20160501       10    20160722       47    20161002        9    20160722
```

meaning, the `Date of MAX` is of `Date 2` because that was the date at which the MAX was measured.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a more general solution using offset:-

```
=MAX(N(OFFSET(D2,0,COLUMN(A:D)*3)))
```

to find the largest value - put this in (say) R2.

Then find a match for it and pick out the corresponding date:-

```
=OFFSET(C2,0,MATCH(R2,N(OFFSET(D2,0,COLUMN(A:D)*3)),0)*3)
```

assuming the dates and values are every third column.

These are array formulae and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If the last value really was in P21 you would have to give a row offset as well as a column offset.

Comment: Thank you @TomSharpe for your suggestion. Interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a **dirty** but simple solution (don't know why I didn't think of it at first):

```
 =IF(G2>=MAX(G2,J2,M2,P21),F2,IF(J2>=MAX(G2,J2,M2,P21),I2,IF(M2>=MAX(G2,J2,M2,P21),L2,O2)))
```

where the pairs (4 of them) are at FG, IJ, LM, OP. Not elegant but does the job.